# Compare POSIXct variables

Tags: r

I have a dataset containing two POSIXct variables: start_date and end_date. Both have the format: '%Y/%M/%D %H-%M%-S'. 
I want to create a new dummy variable indicating if start_date and end_date happened in the same day.

Thanks,

Comment: Convert the start and end dates to date class and then compare the results: as.Date(start_date)==as.Date(end_date)

Comment: You might want to use `identical(as.Date(start_date), as.Date(end_date))` as discussed in the help for `==` (see `?"=="`).